# Create Square Overlay that covers current region in MKMapView

Tags: ios, ios7, mkmapview, mkoverlay, mkpolygon

How can I create a Square Overlay that will cover the current region of my MKMapView. My MKMapView is set with coordinates of the users current location but they are centre coordinates. How do I calculate the square coordinates so I can create a square overlay that fits perfectly in the current view?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `centerCoordinate` and `region` properties of `MKMapView` and then create a `MKPolygon` overlay by extracting the four corners, as in the code below:

```
    vertex[0]=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(map.centerCoordinate.latitude+map.region.span.latitudeDelta/2.,map.centerCoordinate.longitude-map.region.span.longitudeDelta/2.);
    vertex[1]=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(map.centerCoordinate.latitude+map.region.span.latitudeDelta/2.,map.centerCoordinate.longitude+map.region.span.longitudeDelta/2.);
    vertex[2]=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(map.centerCoordinate.latitude-map.region.span.latitudeDelta/2.,map.centerCoordinate.longitude+map.region.span.longitudeDelta/2.);
    vertex[3]=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(map.centerCoordinate.latitude-map.region.span.latitudeDelta/2.,map.centerCoordinate.longitude-map.region.span.longitudeDelta/2.);
    MKPolygon *square = [MKPolygon polygonWithCoordinates:vertex count:4];
```

Then you add the polygon as an overlay:

```
[map addOverlay:square]
```

Finally in your `mapView:rendererForOverlay:` you define your square rendered based on the polygon overlay:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id)overlay {  
    if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]]) {
        MKPolygonRenderer *renderer = [[MKPolygonRenderer alloc] initWithPolygon:(MKPolygon *)overlay];
        renderer.fillColor = [[UIColor redColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.25];
        return renderer;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You have no idea how much you have helped me out! Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!